# Rails using unkown config file for database connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-connection

I have a weird problem.

I have set my database.yml file to use sqlite3 for all three (production, test, dev) databases

1. I create a new rails project with all defaults.
2. I fire up rail server using WEBrick
3. I get "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished" error
4. I try $rake db:create
5. I get the following error: 
   specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.
6. I install pg and postgres server and I get

fe_sendauth: no password supplied Error on the webpage

1. I try $rake db:create  again on the console and get
2. fe_sendauth: no password supplied  (which I know is a postgres password error)
3. It seems that Rails is choosing a different database adapter than in my database.yml file.

I don't know where it could be. It even seems to be looking for a specific database that I used in some previous project. Therefore Rails must be looking at someother config file.

Can someone help.

Comment: What happens when you do `rails dbconsole` from that specific project directory?

Comment: Are you using `Heroku`? By the way, do you get these errors in `development` too?

Answer (score 0):

Add  sqlite3 gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

and set `sqlite3` as adapter in your `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: That's what I have done. Is there any other config file that rails could be looking in....

Comment: The error described on step 5 indicates that the adaptar specified is `postgresql`. Make sure that you set `sqlite3` as adapter and try again. The only file that configures database access in a Rails project is `config/database.yml`